# Matplotlib AxesGrid equal visible size for graphs with different range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple function in one figure. The graphs are aranged in a 2x2 matrix. function1 and function2 share a common y axis, function1 and function3 share a common x axis. I do not want spaces between the plots. I want all plots to occupy the same space on my screen, regardless of their range.

The following code almost does what I want, but it does not scale well.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

x = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
y1 = x
y2 = 0.1*x**2
y3 = x**3

fig = plt.figure()
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(2,2), axes_pad=0.0, share_all=True)
grid[0].plot(x,y1)                                              
grid[2].plot(x,y2)
grid[1].plot(x,y3)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The problem here is that function3 looks pretty much flat and does not use the space well. If I choose `share_all=False`, then  the plots have a different size.

What I want is a plot similar to `share_all=True`, but have the y axis of function3 to be within the range (0,0.1). The y axis of function1 and function2 should remain (-1,1) How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the requirements, there seems no need for `AxesGrid` to be used. Using normal `plt.subplots`, one would get the following result, which seems to be what is desired

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
y1 = x
y2 = 0.1*x**2
y3 = x**3

fig, grid = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex="col", sharey="row")
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
grid[0,0].plot(x,y1)                                              
grid[1,0].plot(x,y2)
grid[0,1].plot(x,y3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Do you have an idea on how to keep the x labels from overlapping? I am fine if they range from -1.2 to 1.2, just don't want any space between the plots.

Comment: Nevermind, I can use `grid[0,0].set_xlim([-1.2,1.2])`. Ugly (because I need to do it by hand), but it works.

Comment: Well, using `set_xlim` would  be my suggestion as well. Other than that, one would need to subclass the locator to set some limits on possible ticklabel locations or the formatter to ommit certain labels; this would be worth a completely new question, if indeed desired.